# Knowing whether a MotionEvent occurred inside a view

Tags: android, view, motionevent

Is it possible to create a method that receive an event and a view and determines whether the event happened in within the view coordinates?

Something along the lines of:

```
private boolean isEventOnTopOfView(MotionEvent event, View view) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

This implementation seems to work for me:

```
 private boolean isEventOnTopOfView(MotionEvent event, View view) {
    return isViewContains(view,(int)event.getRawX(),(int)event.getRawY());
}

private boolean isViewContains(View view, int rx, int ry) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    int w = view.getWidth();
    int h = view.getHeight();

    if (rx < x || rx > x + w || ry < y || ry > y + h) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly simpler implementation in Kotlin:

```
private fun isEventOnTopOfView(event: MotionEvent, view: View): Boolean {
  return Rect().apply(view::getGlobalVisibleRect)
    .contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())
}
```